# Magento 2.3 OpenSource - How to implement Stopwords in ElasticSearch 6.x

Tags: magento2, search, elasticsearch, search-terms

Having custom module dependency injection as follows:

1. `di.xml` in `app/code/Custom/Stopwords/etc` directory.

   ```
   <type name="Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\Query\Preprocessor\Stopwords">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="stopwordsDirectory" xsi:type="string">app/code/Custom/Stopwords/etc/stopwords</argument>
    </arguments>
   ```
2. `stopwords_en_US.csv` in `app/code/Custom/Stopwords/etc/stopwords` directory copied from vendor.

[Dev docs guide which i'm referring](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-config-stopwords.html)

**Edit**

I would like to add few stopwords in the `.csv` file.
Have added the stop-words as follows:

**more**
**less**
**some**
**few**
**other**
**misc**
**all**

Issue - after adding the above stop-words it is not getting applied.

Comment: Is there any question or problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue that you had following the documentation provided.  You were following the **Change Stopword Directory** instead you want to follow the instructions under [**To change the directory from your module**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-config-stopwords.html#to-change-directory-stopwords)

In you custom module etc/di.xml file add in the following

```
<type name="Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\Query\Preprocessor\Stopwords">
<arguments>
   <argument name="stopwordsModule" xsi:type="string">Your_Module</argument>
   <argument name="stopwordsDirectory" xsi:type="string">stopwords</argument>
</arguments>
```

Then make sure to copy `vendor\magento\module-elasticsearch\etc\stopwords\stopwords.csv` to `app/code/Your/Module/etc/stopwords/stopwords.csv` and add your words at the end of the file adding a new line for each word.

Once you are done I recommend rebuilding the indexes.