# Stopwords not working in Magento 2.3 for ElasticSearch 6.0+

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2.2, magento-2.0

I want to implement stopwords functionality in Magento 2.3 but it is not working.
I am overriding the file stopwords.csv using a custom module.

Someone, please suggest the solution.

Thanks,
Rashi

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/299451/magento-2-3-opensource-how-to-implement-stopwords-in-elasticsearch-6-x

Comment: Thanks @Pramod I followed the same but still this solution didn't worked for me.